# Why is group velocity greater than phase velocity in glass?

Tags: optics, waves, phase-velocity

I'm learning with Kenneth Krane Modern Physics 3ed.

28-(b)
When white light travels through glass, the phase velocity of each wavelength depends on the wavelength. (This is
the origin of dispersion and the breaking up of white light
into its component colors—different wavelengths travel at
different speeds and have different indices of refraction.)
How does v<sub>phase</sub> depend on λ? Is dv<sub>phase</sub>/dλ positive or
negative? Therefore, is v<sub>group</sub> >v<sub>phase</sub> or < v<sub>phase</sub>?
solution
The index of refraction n for light in glass decreases as λ increases (shorter
wavelengths are refracted more than longer wavelengths); that is dn / dλ < 0 .
Because n = c / v<sub>phase</sub> , dn / dλ and dv<sub>phase</sub> / dλ have opposite signs and so dv<sub>phase</sub> / dλ > 0. Thus v<sub>group</sub> > v<sub>phase</sub>.
I don't understand the last formula [v<sub>group</sub> > v<sub>phase</sub>].
I think it should be [v<sub>group</sub> < v<sub>phase</sub>] because of the equation in problem 28-(a)[v<sub>group</sub>=v<sub>phase</sub> - λ(dv<sub>phase</sub>/d<sub>λ</sub>)]. Is the solution wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution *does* indeed look wrong if everything you have supplied is correct. If the equation $$v_\text{group}=v_\text{phase} - \lambda\frac{dv_\text{phase}}{dλ}$$ holds true, *and* $$\frac{dv_\text{phase}}{d\lambda}\gt 0$$ then it is certainly true that $$\boxed{v_\text{phase}\gt v_\text{group}}$$

where of course $\lambda\gt 0$. It is true (in general) that for dispersive mediums like glass, the group velocity is usually smaller than the phase velocity.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I still don't understand. Why it is certainly true that vg>vp? Subtracting λ(dvp/dλ) from vp is vg. Clearly dvp/dλ>0 and λ>0 , then vg<vp. Why am I wrong?

Comment: @Pulsar Please excuse my sloppy algebra. I should have had $v_p\gt v_g$ or $v_g\lt v_p$ You are correct and it's probably a typo.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was wrong because there is a principle I don't know, but the solution was wrong.

Comment: No worries. Good luck with your studies.